# ASP.NET Page_IsValid is not defined

Tags: asp.net

I have the following code :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Historique" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Text="Historique" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClientClick="afficherHisto()" OnClick="Historique_Click" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When I am clicking on the button, it shows the following error :

```
ReferenceError: Page_IsValid is not defined
```

I have other buttons based on this one which have the same problem and I can not find the solution.

Comment: Why are you putting the buttons in an updatepanel? Secondly, you don't have any triggers defined.

Comment: I want my button to show a modal window on click and I am executing server side code on click. I do not want to reload all my page on click

Comment: Can you share your server side code?

Comment: I can not share it, sorry.

Comment: Did you check on Page_IsValid?  If so, it should be Page.IsValid!

Comment: No I do not check Page_IsValid in my Page_Load but what if it is not valid ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117615/discussion-between-kami-and-stan).

Comment: The flag `Page_IsValid` can be used in client code (Javascript). You can check if it is used in `afficherHisto`. In my own code, I use `(typeof Page_IsValid == 'undefined' || Page_IsValid)` to avoid the error that you report.